# Compare two NSStrings representing dates

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsstring, nsdate

I am using `NSSortDescriptor` for comparing two dates; it works well. But I want to compare two date strings like "oct-22,2012 Morning" and "oct-22,2012 Evening".

I have separated each string with a space and compared the dates without the morning/evening strings, but I want to display the entire format above i.e., upcoming status is "oct-22,2012 Morning".

My code for comparing two dates is below:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey: @"convertedDate" ascending:YES] ;
[sortArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];   
GetBuddiesObject *datewiseSortObj;                                   

if([sortArray count]>0)
{
     datewiseSortObj=[sortArray objectAtIndex:0];
     obj.flying=datewiseSortObj.flying;                  
     obj.when=datewiseSortObj.when;
     obj.herenow=datewiseSortObj.herenow;                  
     obj.convertedDate=datewiseSortObj.convertedDate;
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: can u tell me how u r sorting/comparing dates.? r u using '20121021' in this format to compare?

Comment: Iam using this format 2012-10-21 04:00:00 +0000

Comment: is it possible to change ur date format for comparison to '20121021' so that u can compare in a integer wise, and for adding comparison of morning/noon/evening u can add one more digit to that 1/2/3 respectively.. after sorting from the last digit u can come to know wthr it is morn/noon/even..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The safest approach is to use a date formatter to convert the strings to NSDate object then compare those using standard techniques.